# Slidify - diacritic marks issue: different title slide font in RStudio Knit HTML view and slidify html output

Tags: r, fonts, slidify

I am developing a presentation with the use of `R` `slidify` function. In my presentation I use **diacritic marks** from Polish language (Ą,Ć,Ę,Ł,Ń,Ó,Ś,Ź,Ż). I have noticed that their display (only in case of the presentation title slide) does differ depending on whether I render its html view via `Knit HTML` button in `RStudio` or I view the html file output generated by the `slifidy` function.

This is a screen from a "Knit HTML button view" presentation title slide:

[image]

This is a screen from an html file output generated by the `slifidy` function (in which I additionally marked some of outstandingly displayed marks):

[image]

**Question:** why does such difference in a font type occur and, more important, how to avoid this? (Please note it happens only in the title slide.)

My presentation begins with the structure:

```
---
title       : Mąlarądóałatrią o (ą,ć,ę,ł,ń,ó,ś,ź,ż ; Ą,Ć,Ę,Ł,Ń,Ó,Ś,Ź,Ż) 
subtitle    : Podtytuł mąlarądóałatrią o (ą,ć,ę,ł,ń,ó,ś,ź,ż ; Ą,Ć,Ę,Ł,Ń,Ó,Ś,Ź,Ż) 
author      : Imię Nazwisko 
job         : Pisanie prezentacji o (ą,ć,ę,ł,ń,ó,ś,ź,ż ; Ą,Ć,Ę,Ł,Ń,Ó,Ś,Ź,Ż) 
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
---

## Wstęp o ą,ć,ę,ł,ń,ó,ś,ź,ż ; Ą,Ć,Ę,Ł,Ń,Ó,Ś,Ź,Ż

[...]
```

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the encoding of the document. I believe when you do hit Knit HTML, the document is encoded as UTF-8, which leads it to slidify correctly, while the slidify function does not take care of it automatically. I will investigate and figure out the root cause.

Comment: In RStudio, while saving the Rmd file, can you try Save with Encoding, and ensure that you are saving it as UTF-8?

Comment: **Ramnath**, thank you for your interest! I do have UTF-8 set as *default encoding for source files*. For being 100% sure I just did the 'save with encoding -> UTF-8', and the result after running `slidify` is the same. Would you consider it a good temporary solution to set a font type to the type we can see in the first screen? (As in the second screen the diacritic marks are displayed *correctly*, it is just the font type which is inconsistent...)

Comment: Ah. I see what you are talking about now. This is puzzling as to why the font type should change. Explicitly setting the font type might be a good idea, but I am not sure how you can do that.

Comment: I would guess it is related to the fonts family definitions in .css documents, that are different in `io2012` framework (which I use) and in the other one .css that is used during *after hitting Knit HTML* rendering. I have just changed the order of the font families in the file `.\mydeck\libraries\frameworks\io2012\css\slidify.css` - set the `Calibri` font as the first one - and now the title slide is displayed ok.

Comment: @Marciszka I'm having a similar issue and changed the first one but i still get a different font as you show in the first image. I'm using the dev version of both slidify and slidifyLibraries. Could you answer with the content of the css this question?

Comment: @[Martín Bel], I did so, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments below my question, I eventually decided to solve this problem by modifying the `.css` file: `\mydeck\libraries\frameworks\io2012\css\slidify.css`.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjpx4kclpj2gwxa/slidify_default.css) is the default `.css` file I receive after first `slidify` over a document, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmxbndh4lzwah64/slidify_customized.css) you can find customized `.css` file which deals with the font type inconsistency. (Of course, in the `slidify` files directory it is going to exist under "old" `slidify.css` name.) The only changes I applied are these under

```
/* Styles for Title Slide */
```

section.

Comment: Marta, I'm unable to download your .css file. Could you reupload it, please?